# How to evaluate if a list obeys the Normal distribution?

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am processing a data when I encountered this problem. I use the way of plotting the "normal probability plot" to show the result

The list I have is:

```
t1={0.0330584, 0.0288738, 0.0303384, 0.0330584, 0.034523, 0.0311753, 
0.029083, 0.0280369, 0.0332676, 0.0334768, 0.0338953, 0.0311753, 
0.0305476, 0.0332676, 0.0269907, 0.0332676, 0.0278276, 0.0261538, 
0.0286645, 0.0311753}
```

I want to use the following code to get the "Normal score" to shown if t1 is obeying normal distribution.

```
edist = EstimatedDistribution[t1, NormalDistribution[\[Mu],\[Sigma]]]

ListPlot[Transpose[{t1, 
     InverseCDF[edist, (Ordering[t1] + 1.0/6)/(
      Length@t1 + 1/3)]}], Joined -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 22] & /@ {"Normal Score", "Data"})]
```

But the function is not giving me the correct result.

[image]

So in Excel, the function RANK() can give the ordering of a certain value in a list. If there are two elements with same value, they will have same ordering after RANK() is applied. But in Mathematica, the function Ordering[] will give different value for same valued element.
Is there another function can do this task?

> What I used to do with Excel

When I use Excel to process it, I use two functions in Excel: RANK() and COUNT()
the E column is obtained by

```
       (RANK(C1,$C$1:$C$20)+1/6)/(COUNT(C1,$C$1:$C$20)+1/3)
```

Then, I use =NORMSINV(E1) to get the final value of F column

After that, I can plot the C column and F column to shown the value of C column is obeying Normal distribution(whether if they are forming a line).

[image]

Comment: The problem is I don't know if there is  functions in Mathematica can reproduce the results of the function RANK() and NORMSINV() in Excel.

Comment: Also, is there better ways to shown if my data obeys Normal Distribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [`QuantilePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantilePlot.html)

```
QuantilePlot[t1]
```

[image]

There are others as well.  Have a look at the *Distribution Fits* section [Statistical Visualisation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StatisticalVisualization.html) guide.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`DistributionFitTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html) to test whether data is normally distributed.  A small p-value suggests that it is unlikely that the data is normally distributed.

```
t1 = {0.0330584, 0.0288738, 0.0303384, 0.0330584, 0.034523, 0.0311753, 
   0.029083, 0.0280369, 0.0332676, 0.0334768, 0.0338953, 0.0311753, 0.0305476,
    0.0332676, 0.0269907, 0.0332676, 0.0278276, 0.0261538, 0.0286645, 
   0.0311753};

dft = DistributionFitTest[t1, Automatic, "HypothesisTestData"];

dft["TestDataTable", All]
```

[image]

```
edist = EstimatedDistribution[t1, NormalDistribution[μ, σ]];

{μ, σ} = List @@ edist;

Show[
 Histogram[t1, Automatic, "PDF"],
 SmoothHistogram[t1, PlotStyle -> Thick],
 Plot[PDF[edist, x], {x, μ - 3 σ, μ + 3 σ},
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get a quick visual peek at the distribution of the data, we can do:

```
GraphicsRow[Table[
  Show[
    Histogram[Sort[(t1 - Mean@t1)/StandardDeviation@t1], k, "Probability"]
    , Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -5, 5}]
  ]
  , {k, 5, 15, 5]
```

resulting in

[image]

It doesn't *look* all that normal, but the dataset is small, so of course it's hard to tell. Probably a real statistics test as mentioned in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102252/29734) to the question is more useful.